# Override ShortCut Keys on .NET RichTextBox

Tags: c#, winforms, richtextbox

I'm using a `RichTextBox` (.NET WinForms 3.5) and would like to override some of the standard ShortCut keys....
For example, I don't want <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>I</kbd> to make the text italic via the RichText method, but to instead run my own method for processing the text.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>I</kbd> isn't one of the default shortcuts affected by the ShortcutsEnabled property.

The following code intercepts the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>I</kbd> in the KeyDown event so you can do anything you want inside the if block, just make sure to suppress the key press like I've shown.

```
private void YourRichTextBox_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
    if ((Control.ModifierKeys & Keys.Control) == Keys.Control && e.KeyCode == Keys.I)
    {
        // do whatever you want to do here...
        e.SuppressKeyPress = true;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Set the RichtTextBox.ShortcutsEnabled property to true and then handle the shortcuts yourself, using the KeyUp event. E.G.

```
using System;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace WindowsFormsApplication1
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            this.textBox1.ShortcutsEnabled = false;
            this.textBox1.KeyUp += new KeyEventHandler(textBox1_KeyUp);
        }

        void textBox1_KeyUp(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.Control == true && e.KeyCode == Keys.X)
                MessageBox.Show("Overriding ctrl+x");
        }
    }
}
```