# How to prevent command keys from being processed by hosting form when control has focus

Tags: c#, winforms, keyboard-shortcuts

I'm looking for a way to cancel keystrokes of keyboard shortcuts or command keys (like F1 or CTRL+O) when a control is focused. If possible on the control level.

Imagine I have a control (a simple textbox for example) hosted on a form. I've set keyboard shortcuts for commands like Open (CTRL+O) or Help (F1). If the control has the keyboard focus and I press one of the commands I want to prevent the execution of the shortcut command.

I would prefer a solution where I can handle those keystrokes and prevent them from "bubbling up" at the control level and not at the form level.

Comment: You could set/unset a global flag and use it as condition to prematurely quit an event. But seriously, how does 'editing the controls value' change the context of your application? Whatever you are doing there, this sounds wrong...

Comment: I'm trying to create a terminal emulation control and while it has the focus I need to send F1 to the remote server and suppress opening the help file. Make sense?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The only solution I've found was to implement/override ProcessCmdKey function on the control level:

```
protected override bool ProcessCmdKey(ref Message msg, Keys keyData)
{
    if (keyData >= Keys.F1 && keyData <= Keys.F24)
    {
        WndProc(ref msg);
        return true;
    }
    return base.ProcessCmdKey(ref msg, keyData);
}
```

I also needed to remove all keyboard shortcuts from my mainform and implement the same way to handle them.

Comment: NOTE: In VB.NET you need to `Return MyBase.ProcessCmdKey(msg, keyData)`

Answer (score 2):

You can use the KeyDown-event:

```
    void DropDownBox_KeyDown(object sender, System.Windows.Forms.KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        switch (e.KeyCode)
        {
            case Keys.Down:
            case Keys.Up:
                ShowPopup();
                e.SuppressKeyDown = true; // Don't pass it to the underlying control
                break;
        }
    }
```

**If this is not enough** - like overriding Tab or any other base keystroke, here's a **[very good article about keyhandling](http://www.devx.com/dotnet/Article/39607/1954)**

Answer (score 1):

Use `e.SuppressKeyPress = true;` in keydown event:   I have made a access key for check box as ALT + C and it is working well.

```
 private void cboViewType_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
        {
            if ((Control.ModifierKeys & Keys.Control) == Keys.Control || e.KeyCode == Keys.F1 || ((Control.ModifierKeys & Keys.Alt) == Keys.Alt && e.KeyCode == Keys.C))
            {
                // do whatever you want to do here...
                MessageBox.Show("key overridden");
                e.SuppressKeyPress = true;
            }
            //e.Handled = true;   // will not work for overriding the shortcut etc.
        }
```

Ref:  [Override ShortCut Keys on .NET RichTextBox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/260716/override-shortcut-keys-on-net-richtextbox)

Answer (score 0):

You can stop "bubbling up" for the majority of keyboard events with setting the `KeyEventArgs.Handled = true` in the `KeyDown` event handler of any focusable control.
It intercepts ALT-F4, or F1, but will not intercepts system combos, like ALT-TAB.

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void textBox1_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        e.Handled = true;
    }
}
```

Comment: whoever voted down would you explain? because as I see the answer is exactly what the questioner wanted to know.

Comment: SO asked this:  the control has the keyboard focus and I press one of the commands I want to prevent the execution of the shortcut command. Ref [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7557442/e-handled-vs-supresskeypress) to know that what e.handled and e.SuppressKeyPress.

Comment: setting Handled = true does not prevent a KeyPress from occurring. so the shortcut keys will fire the associated command.